# Sent emails not syncing properly

Tags: iphone, email

When I send an email from my iPhone the sent email does not end up in the "sent" box on my Mac, in my mail.  It ends up going into a different box, named"sent messages" under "mobile Me.  I want it to sync properly so all of my devices are the same.  Does anyone know what I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you would want to do in this case, is to click on the Sent box on your Mac, then go to the Mailbox menu and select 'Use This Mailbox For >' and select Sent.